# csv to xlsx - when import its always blank?

Tags: python, csv, xlsx, python-3.4, xlsxwriter

Trying to convert a csv into an xlsx for later manipulation. But no matter what I do its always blank(creates xlsx and adds sheet name fine, no data ever appears though)

Really confused, tried all sorts. The below is the most full piece of code I have used.

```
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

workbook = Workbook("test.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Raw_Data")

with open("C:\Console2\\csv.test",'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for r, row in enumerate(reader):
        for c, col in enumerate(row):
            worksheet.write(r, c, col)
```

I do not understand fully the bit after reader line, but it seems all related code I find uses this, I have tried "for statement" for writing a normal csv and that did not work either.

EDIT - issue seems to be with the reader variable, not sure why as its worked on other code fine.

Update - looks like the code overwrites the original csv, dont know why exactly, i just want to read the file and keep contents.

Comment: Try to add `workbook.close()` at the end of your script.

Comment: I was understand impression from something I read that with statement automatically closes opened files. I still tried as you suggested, and its the same, blank file being created.

Comment: You don't have to close `f`, that's right. But you may have to close `workbook`. I haven't used *xlswriter* myself, but accoring to [this](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_demo.html#ex-demo) example, you should close the workbook. It might be so that the actual content isn't written before you close the workbook.

Comment: tried it in many places and no change, looks like my reader variable is blank, but I dont get why, done almost identical code for writing csvs and had no problems.

Comment: @Kuzen Check name of the file. `"C:\Console..." is missing escaped `\`, it shall read `"C:\\Console2..." This might make your file unreachable.

Comment: Filename is correct, if i change it i get error - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Console2\\csv.test'

Comment: @SteinarLima turns out you were correct. after i fixed the issue, had to close it.

Comment: @Kuzen Good to hear. I summarized it in an answer :)

Comment: @SteinarLima thanks again, this coding lark is mad :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close `workbook` to make it work:

```
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

workbook = Workbook("test.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Raw_Data")

with open("C:\Console2\\csv.test",'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for r, row in enumerate(reader):
        for c, col in enumerate(row):
            worksheet.write(r, c, col)

workbook.close()
```

See [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_demo.html#ex-demo) for an example.

Comment: Once i fixed the blank csv problem, this was indeed the correct code. many thanks for assistance.